# Does the hamcrest library for JUnit has an API to test public variables rather than properties

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I am trying to test public variables having specific values. The problem is that I am testing public variables, not JavaBean.

```
Assert.assertThat(clientMapper.entries, Matchers.<ClientMapper.MapperEntry>hasItem(
    Matchers.allOf(
            Matchers.hasProperty("from", Matchers.is("/v1")),
            Matchers.hasProperty("to", Matchers.is("/v2"))
    )
));
```

And the class I am testing is

```
public static class MapperEntry {
    public String from;
    public String to;
}
```

The test fails because it does not find a JavaBean property `from` and `to`, which is understandable, but how can I test public fields?

**UPDATE**: I am trying to find solution for java 7

Comment: Are we talking about Java 8 here? In that case it would be easy with a stream... Something like... `assertThat( clientMapper.entries().filter(p -> "/v1".equals(p.from) && "/v2".equals(p.to)).size, greaterThan(0) );`

Comment: no, unfortunately java7

Comment: Is the `MapperEntry.equals` method overridden to return true, if the from/to are equal? In that case `hasItem` with an appropriate `MapperEntry` as a parameter would be enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NitorCreations' matchers library](https://github.com/NitorCreations/matchers) has matchers for fields:

```
Assert.assertThat(clientMapper.entries, Matchers<ClientMapper.MapperEntry>hasItem(
  Matchers.allOf(
        com.nitorcreations.Matchers.hasField("from", Matchers.is("/v1")),
        com.nitorcreations.Matchers.hasField("to", Matchers.is("/v2"))
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Public fields are rare in Java, that's probably why there isn't one. You will have to write your own `Matcher` to handle this.

If the class had a proper `toString()` implementation, then you could use a string or regexp matcher.